# How to get the value of a cell specifies the GridView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to get the value of a cell of a GridView. When the user click on the grid, I need to know which line button, and then get the value of the cell.
I'm trying to use the following code, but not work.

```
 protected void gvSearch_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            int row = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            string tst = gvSearch.Rows[row].Cells[1].Text;
        }
    }
```

I do not know if I'm using the right event to get on my goal. If someone can help me, I thank you.

Comment: What does your e.CommandArgument contain? Please provide some .aspx code

Comment: Yes, I searched, but everything I find does not work, there are always errors.

Comment: What does tst show when you debug? Does it have a value? Presumably you're using 'select' as your command name, can you tell me if any of it works when you debug?

Comment: Is returning empty. tst == ""

Comment: This code looks right. Could you paste your gridview Html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution!

Am using BoundField.

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Código Área" DataField=" <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Denominação Área" DataField="areaName" />

protected void gvSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String lastName = gvSearch.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    }
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
protected void gvSearch_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        string pc = gVSearch.Rows[int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())].Cells[1].Text;
    }
}
```