# Can't get row values from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is the loop I'm using. I get the correct number of rows and columns back, so I'm assuming I'm binding correctly.

However `Text` is always empty. Why?

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        string cellText = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text;
    }
}
```

I have found a few [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437137/cant-get-values-from-rows-cells-in-gridview) but they don't help.

**Edit 1**

This is my GridView with one record

[image]

The only empty value is under Responsibility.

From Ehsan Sajjad's answer below, I understand that my code would always get the last value, i.e. "Classics".

Is that correct?

If it is, then why am I getting empty `Text` for all columns?

**Edit 2**

I've solved it myself. Thanks to those who helped in this thread. See my own answer below.

Comment: celltext is overriding again and again...and it will give you value of last cell....

Comment: I see. But how do I define cellText out of the loop?

Comment: You can use Array or List for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gridview was using `DynamicFields`.

The solution was simply to replace all my `DynamicFields` with standard `BoundFields` and BOOM all the data was there.

Next time I won't be using `DynamicData` framework, that's for sure.

[On this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315951/gridview-empty-rows-when-exporting-to-csv-solved) you can find the complete scenario of my original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Easisest way is to use :

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
for(int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count, i++)
{

    String cellText = row.Cells[i].Text;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manish. I've tried this before but `Text` always returns an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string cellText = "";

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Rows[i].Cells.Count; k++)
    {
        cellText += GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't help. I don't see why counting the cells would have made any difference. Can you explain please?

Comment: does your gridview generate fields auto ? or you declare your gridview columns manually ? if it's auto-generate,there is no column in gridview and GridView1.Columns.Count is always 0

Comment: I set the property `AutoGenerateColumns` to false. In debugging I can see I get the correct number of columns and rows. That's why I'm confused that `Cell.Text` is empty.

Answer (score -1):

your answer lies in the link which you mentioned in you question, your cells might have controls inside it try accessing it with the help of row.Cells[1].Controls collection.
lastly set a break point in loop and check are you able to get into the second loop  ? i tried loading gridview with the help of SqlDataSource and tried to access value like you did and i were not able to get into the second loop.
perhaps this link might help you.
[How to get the value of a cell specifies the GridView ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653344/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-cell-specifies-the-gridview-asp-net)

Comment: I don't think so. All columns are boundfields (no templateField, for instance)

Comment: Can you please post html code of your gridview, so that i can provide better answer

Comment: Apologies for stating the wrong info in my previous comment.