# Gridview empty rows when exporting to CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, gridview

This question has been prompted by further discussion on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674555/export-gridview-data-into-csv-file/6674589?noredirect=1#comment43079606_6674589).

The following is the routine I'm using for creating the CSV file.
Everything works great, except that I only get the columns headers and no rows.

```
   protected void CSVReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PeopleReportTest.csv");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");

       GridView1.AllowSorting = false;
       GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
       GridView1.DataBind();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int k = 1; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            //add separator
            sb.Append(GridView1.Columns[k].HeaderText + ',');
        }
        //append new line
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                //add separator
                sb.Append(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text + ',');
            }
            //append new line
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
        Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

On inspection, I can see that `GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text` always returns an empty value.

So the issue might be with the structure of my gridview. I know that the code wouldn't work if I had `TemplateFields`, but I have only one and it's set to invisible.

All other fields are `DynamicFields`. Could that be the problem?

Here's the markup:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
            CssClass="table table-condensed borderless"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
            DataSourceID="GridDataSource"
            DataKeyNames="PersonID" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" PageSize="15">
            <Columns>
                <asp:templatefield itemstyle-width="0%" visible="false">
                    <itemtemplate>
                        <aspf:dynamichyperlink id="detailshyperlink" runat="server"
                            text="details" />
                    </itemtemplate>

                </asp:templatefield>

                <asp:DynamicField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>
                <asp:DynamicField DataField="PersonCategory" HeaderText="Category" />
                <asp:DynamicField DataField="PositionDescription" HeaderText="Position" />
                <asp:DynamicField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Topic" />
                <asp:DynamicField DataField="FellowsResponsibility" HeaderText="Responsibility" />
                <asp:DynamicField DataField="PartnerSurname" HeaderText="Partner"/>
            </Columns>

            <PagerStyle CssClass="footer" />
            <PagerTemplate>
                <asp:GridViewPager runat="server" />
            </PagerTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                There are currently no items in this table.
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've found what the problem was.

I couldn't find other similar scenarios around, so I'm answering my own question in case someone will find it helpful.

The solution was simply to replace all my `DynamicFields` with standard `BoundFields` and BOOM all the data was there.

Next time I won't be using `DynamicData` framework, that's for sure.

Comment: great @dura, pleased that you found it on your own. cheers!!! additionally you can mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will accept my answer when I'm allowed.